# How to compile and run H2 TriggerSample

Tags: command-line, triggers, h2

I copied TriggerSample.java to this directory. Then:

javac -cp h2-1.3.168.jar TriggerSample.java

creates

TriggerSample$MyTrigger.class  ... and ... TriggerSample.class

Then:
java TriggerSample

says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TriggerSample (wrong name: org/h2/samples/TriggerSample)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

also no go with:

java org.h2.samples.TriggerSample

java org/h2/samples/TriggerSample

How exactly to run that example from the command line?

Comment: Why don't you use an IDE (Eclipse or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular Java problem. The package name of class `TriggerSample` is `org.h2.samples`. You should use the directory name `org/h2/samples`.

- Create a directory org/h2/samples

  `mkdir org/h2/samples`
- Move the file `TriggerSample.java` to that directory
- Run

  `javac -cp h2-1.3.168.jar org/h2/samples/TriggerSample.java`
- Then run

  `java -cp h2-1.3.168.jar:. org.h2.samples.TriggerSample`

Or: remove the package declaration of the file `TriggerSample.java`.